# How can I speed up or slow down a background music track with iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, audio

Is there an easy way to control the playback speed/tempo of a sound file loop played using Audio Queue Services?  For example, if a game is playing background music, I want to make the BGM speed up as time runs out, but without changing the pitch of the music.  Thx!

Comment: Nope, I did not find a suitably "easy" answer yet :-( and no time to try out the more complex hints.

Comment: With iOS 7 you can now do this with audio queues.  See 
[this stackoverflow thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215061/audioqueue-kaudioqueueparam-pitch/18411436#18411436

Answer (score 1):

There's no trivial way to do this that I know of. On the Mac, you'd presumably use Audio Units to do this, but I think the support for those is limited on the iPhone SDK.

You can do some processing during your AudioQueue playback callback, between AudioFileReadPackets() and AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer() but I think speed-shifting without changing the tone will require rather a lot of CPU time.

It'd probably be easier to have more than one recording of the music, and switch files during a silent passage of the music.