# How to slow down or speed up the playback of audio when using Audio Queue Services?

Tags: iphone, audioqueueservices

Is that possible? How is this done in theory? Would I simply make a very small buffer packet size and then delay the playback artificially? I assume that's the low-brain way? How could I do it in such a way that the sound is smooth and doesn't suck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delaying playback will cause stuttering in the audio. Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448748/how-can-i-speed-up-or-slow-down-a-background-music-track-with-iphone-sdk) might point the way?

Answer (score 2):

AudioQueueSetParameter with kAudioQueueParam_PlayRate should do the trick

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioQueueSetParameter