# audioqueue kAudioQueueParam_Pitch

Tags: pitch, audioqueue

The documentation for Audio Queue Services under OS 10.6 now includes a pitch parameter:

kAudioQueueParam_Pitch
The number of cents to pitch-shift the audio queue’s playback, in the range -2400through 2400 cents (where 1200 cents corresponds to one musical octave.)
This parameter is usable only if the time/pitch processor is enabled.

Other sections of the same document still say that volume is the only available parameter, and I can't find any reference to the time/pitch processor mentioned above.

Does anyone know what this refers to? Directly writing a value to the parameter has no effect on playback (although no error is thrown). Similarly writing the volume setting does work.

Frustrating as usual with no support from Apple.

Answer (score 2):

This is only available on OSX until iOS 7.  If you look at AudioQueue.h you'll find it is conditionally available only on iOS 7. [note: on re-reading I see you were referring to OS X, not iOS, but hopefully the following is cross-platform]

Also, you need to enable the queue for time_pitch *before* setting the time_pitch algorithm, and only the Spectral algorithm supports pitch (all of them support rate)

```
result = AudioQueueNewOutput(&(pAqData->mDataFormat), aqHandleOutputBuffer, pAqData,
                             0, kCFRunLoopCommonModes   , 0, &(pAqData->mQueue));
// enable time_pitch
UInt32 trueValue = 1;
AudioQueueSetProperty(pAqData->mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_EnableTimePitch, &trueValue, sizeof(trueValue)); 
UInt32 timePitchAlgorithm = kAudioQueueTimePitchAlgorithm_Spectral; // supports rate and pitch
 AudioQueueSetProperty(pAqData->mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_TimePitchAlgorithm, &timePitchAlgorithm, sizeof(timePitchAlgorithm));
```